# Learning a PAC-lernable using agnostic-PAC framework

Tags: machine-learning, pac-learning

given H a family of functions which is PAC lernable such that for $\epsilon$ error and  $\delta $ confidence interval it required $m(\epsilon,\delta)$ samples.

I understood that if we learn H under agnostic-PAC the same function will require more samples for the same accuracy meaning:

$m_{agnostic}(\epsilon,\delta)>m(\epsilon,\delta)$

since H is PAC learnable we know that H contain a realizable solution with 0 error, so why is the number of samples still larger for agnostic -PAC?

Comment: "since H is PAC learnable we know that H contain a realizable solution with 0 error" 

no. in the agnostic setup, you have distributions under which no hypothesis in H is realizable (i.e., with 0 error).

Comment: thank you for answering, so as i understand the exitance of a realizable solution is unrelatable to the assumed distribution of sample, prediction pairs.?